# How to add sourcemaps to rollbar? Angular 8

Tags: angular, angular8, rollbar

I've just added rollbar to my project and need to add sourcemaps, I can see where to add them in the control panel but unsure of the best way to produce them from Angular 8.

Any tips out there?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.